# Historische Erklärung für Position des NICHT im Satz

Tags: word-order, history

Ich habe gestern von einer Freundin folgende Frage bekommen: Warum steht **nicht** in vielen Fällen nicht vor dem Verb, sondern irgendwo am Satzende?

Ich meine, sie wollte keine grammatikalische, sondern eine geschichtliche Erklärung, wie es dazu kam. Da ich sowohl kein Deutscher als auch kein Sprachwissenschaftler bin, konnte ich ihr da nicht weiterhelfen.

Oder ist die Erklärung ganz einfach? WEIL! :)

Und falls es doch eine Entstehungsgeschichte gibt, gibt es vielleicht auch ein Buch über so was?

Comment: *WEIL----> darum*, soweit ich weiß.

Comment: Gehe nicht über Los, ziehe nicht 4000,- DM ein. Ist die Behauptung überhaupt empirisch belegt? Ich bin zwar Deutscher, aber auch keine 800 Jahre alt. :) Wieso sollte das Nicht nicht am Satzende stehen? Wieso machen das nicht alle so?

Comment: @userunknown "ich verstehe diese Frage nicht" => "I don't understand this question", "das Essen in diesem Restaurant schmeckt mir nicht" => "The food in this restaurant doesn't taste". Also, nicht alle machen das so.

Comment: Das nicht steht immer vor dem Satzteil, der negiert werden soll. Am Ende steht es, wenn der ganze Satz negiert werden soll, weil dann klar ist, dass man nichts anderes als den gesamten Satz meinen kann.

Comment: @Janka "ich kann das nicht bestätigen" :) und nicht "ich nicht kann das bestätigen". Und wie gesagt, mich interessiert die Entstehungsgeschichte, nicht die Grammatik

Comment: Ja, und? *Nicht bestätigen* ist die Negation von *bestätigen*. In der Benutzung als Hilfs- oder Modalverb wird nicht dieses, sondern das dazugehörige Vollverb negiert. Deine Prämisse, "nicht" stünde "meistens am Satzende" stimmt auch weiterhin nicht. Das kommt wie gesagt darauf an, was man negieren will.

Comment: @Janka: "Geh über Los nicht. Ziehe 4000 DM ein nicht"? "Wieso machen das alle so nicht"? Wie kann die Behauptung belegt werden, dass das Nicht meistens am Ende steht? Stimmt das wirklich? In der Dialektik der Aufklärung finde ich 4  " nicht\.", dagegen 140 " nicht ".

Comment: Ich habe diese Behauptung nicht aufgestellt. Deine Frage muss sich an den OP richten.

Comment: @userunknown ich habe meine Frage etwas angepasst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die moderne Sprachwissenschaft geht im Allgemeinen davon aus, dass die Hauptsatzstellung im Deutschen von der Nebensatzstellung abgeleitet ist, was vor allem bedeutet, dass sich Hauptsätze so verhalten, als hätte sich das finite Verb von der Position, die es in einem Nebensatz hätte, nach vorne in die zweite Position bewegt. Das sieht dann etwa so aus:

", dass ich diese Frage **verstehe**."

Das wäre die Satzstellung im Nebensatz. Machen wir einen Hauptsatz daraus:

"Ich **verstehe** diese Frage."

Das finite Verb rutscht also sozusagen nach vorne, aber in gewissen Details verhält es sich, wie wenn es immer noch am Schluss stünde. Ein solches Detail ist eben die Verneinung: Im Nebensatz steht sie vor dem finiten Verb, wo sie (mehr oder weniger) logisch hingehört:

", dass ich diese Frage *nicht* verstehe."

Wenn jetzt das finite Verb nach vorne rutscht, um einen Haupsatz zu bilden, bleibt das "nicht" an der gleichen Stelle:

"Ich verstehe diese Frage *nicht*."

Warum geht das finite Verb im Hauptsatz überhaupt nach vorne, und wie so kommt das "nicht" nicht mit? Wer weiß.

Comment: Das ist natürlich auch keine historische Erklärung, weil ich nicht weiß, seit wann sich im Deutschen die Hauptsatzstellung von der Nebensatzstellung unterscheidet, aber selbst die historische Erklärung müsste, um wirklich eine Erklärung zu sein, beinhalten, warum das finite Verb im Laufe der Geschichte im Hauptsatz nach vorne gerutscht ist, ohne dabei die es modifizierenden Adverbien mitgenommen zu haben, was aber so genau niemand weiß, weil niemand genau weiß, warum sich Sprache wie verändert.

Comment: vielen Dank, das geht schon in die Richtung, die ich gesucht habe. "Die moderne Sprachwissenschaft geht im Allgemeinen davon aus" - > gibt es dazu vielleicht Referenzen? Oder Links?

Comment: Wikipedia hat etwa das [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2-Stellung#Transformationsgrammatik). Darüber, was genau es bedeutet, zu sagen, dass das Verb nach vorne bewegt wird, gibt es übrigens auch keinen echten Konsens, also ob das eine Art Metapher ist, oder ob das Gehirn wirklich jedesmal, wenn man einen Hauptsatz sagt, mit einem Gliedsatz anfängt, oder was auch immer. Was es auf jeden Fall heißt, ist, dass einige Dinge in Haupsätzen so aussehen, wie wenn das Verb noch immer am Schluss stehen würde, eben unter anderem die Verneinung.

Answer (score 0):

Soweit ich weiß, steht es auch nicht immer direkt am Satzende, es kommt auch auf die Zeit oder den Modus an. Hast du denn einen Beispielsatz?

Mir fiel gerade nur der Satz "Ich habe es nicht gemacht." ein und da ist die Erklärung folgende:
Das "nicht" gehört zum Verb "gemacht" irgendwie dazu, also "gemacht" vs. "nicht gemacht". Es ist wie im Englischen, wo man auch sagt "do" vs. "do not", wo es eben nach dem Verb steht, im Spanischen steht das Verneinungswort wieder vor dem Verb.

Wenn du einen Beispielsatz hast, kann ich auch versuchen speziell zu diesem Satz eine Erklärung abzuliefern.

Comment: Danke für deine Antworte. Wie ich aber geschrieben habe, interessiert mich eher die historische Entstehung und nicht die grammatikalische Erklärung

Comment: @MurVotema Dazu gibt es keine "Entstehungsgeschichte", wie du sie willst. Es ist einfach so passiert, weil es am logischsten ist, das Verneinungswort neben das Verb zu stellen. Das ist nicht aufgrund eines Zufalls passiert. Für welche anderen grammatikalischen Regeln gibt es denn Entstehungsgeschichten?

Comment: Es fällt auf, dass "nicht" dort steht, wo auch ein Adverb stehen würde, und das ist auch nicht verwunderlich, da man "nicht" als das Adverb der Verneinung auffassen kann (so wie man "kein" als Adjektiv der Verneinung auffassen kann). Man kann also die Frage verallgemeinern, indem man nach der Position des Adverbs fragt.

Comment: @SerafinaReisinger wahrscheinlich habe ich andere Wahrnehmung für "am logischsten". Vielleicht liegt es daran, dass ich kein Deutsch Muttersprachler bin. Und mit der Entstehung meinte ich die Entstehungsgeschichte der deutschen Sprache.

Comment: @SerafinaReisinger: Alles hat eine Entstehungsgeschichte. Und wenn die Ursache "weil es halt logisch ist" ist, dann ist eben genau das die Entstehungsgeschichte, wobei ich dies als Geschichte doch arg bezweifle. Wenn wir unsere Sprache logisch und unwidersprüchlich entwickelten, dann würden wir bspw. Zahlwörter anders aussprechen (z.B. "147" -> "Hundert Vierzig Sieben", statt erst "Hundert", dann nach rechts "Sieben", dann wieder nach links "u. Vierzig"). Die Geschichte nicht zu kennen und zu sagen "weil es so ist" ist in 100% der Fälle falsch, bzw. in dem Sinne richtig, als es immer zutrifft.